# Seeking and reading large files in a Linux C++ application

Tags: c++, c, linux, gnu, large-files

I am running into integer overflow using the standard *ftell* and *fseek* options inside of G++, but I guess I was mistaken because it seems that *ftell64* and *fseek64* are not available. I have been searching and many websites seem to reference using **lseek** with the *off64_t* datatype, but I have not found any examples referencing something equal to *fseek*. Right now the files that I am reading in are 16GB+ CSV files with the expectation of at least double that.

Without any external libraries what is the most straightforward method for achieving a similar structure as with the *fseek/ftell* pair? My application right now works using the standard GCC/G++ libraries for 4.x.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

fseek64 is a C function. To make it available you'll have to define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 before including the system headers That will more or less define fseek to be actually fseek64. Or do it in the compiler arguments e.g. 
 gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 ....

http://www.suse.de/~aj/linux_lfs.html has a great overviw of large file support on linux:

- Compile your programs with "gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64". This forces all file access calls to use the 64 bit variants. Several types change also, e.g. off_t becomes off64_t. It's therefore important to always use the correct types and to not use e.g. int instead of off_t. For portability with other platforms you should use getconf LFS_CFLAGS which will return -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 on Linux platforms but might return something else on e.g. Solaris. For linking, you should use the link flags that are reported via getconf LFS_LDFLAGS. On Linux systems, you do not need special link flags.
- Define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE and _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE. With these defines you can use the LFS functions like open64 directly.
- Use the O_LARGEFILE flag with open to operate on large files.

Comment: So, I followed your instructions and everything is compiling file. But I seem to still be getting an overflow. How would you use the O_LARGEFILE parameter with fopen64?

Comment: If you compile with -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64, O_LARGEFILE is supplied automatically.  This is not a standard flag; it is used on Linux to keep track of whether the file was opened with large file interfaces.

Comment: You've asked the question as C++, are you using/mixing C file operations with C++ streams , or are you using only the C API ? Also, do you have some test code to reproduce the behavior ? It's paramount that you use the correct types dealing with lengths/offsets.

Comment: I am only using the C API, and have been using off64_t as my types.

Comment: The key to this answer is -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 and is actually what fixed my problem. When using multiple shared libraries my suggestion would be to apply this to all of the build Makefiles.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to stick to ISO C standard interfaces, use [`fgetpos()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetpos.html) and [`fsetpos()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsetpos.html).  However, these functions are only useful for saving a file position and going back to the same position later.  They represent the position using the type `fpos_t`, which is not required to be an integer data type.  For example, on a record-based system it could be a struct containing a record number and offset within the record.  This may be too limiting.

POSIX defines the functions [`ftello()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftello.html) and [`fseeko()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseeko.html), which represent the position using the `off_t` type.  This is required to be an integer type, and the value is a byte offset from the beginning of the file.  You can perform arithmetic on it, and can use `fseeko()` to perform relative seeks.  This will work on Linux and other POSIX systems.

In addition, compile with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` (Linux/Solaris).  This will define `off_t` to be a 64-bit type (i.e. `off64_t`) instead of `long`, and will redefine the functions that use file offsets to be the versions that take 64-bit offsets.  This is the default when you are compiling for 64-bit, so is not needed in that case.

Answer (score 6):

`fseek64()` isn't standard, the compiler docs should tell you where to find it.

Have you tried `fgetpos` and `fsetpos`? They're designed for large files and the implementation typically uses a 64-bit type as the base for fpos_t.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [**fseeko()**](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fseeko.html) with the **_FILE_OFFSET_BITS** preprocessor symbol set to **64**?

This will give you an **fseek()**-like interface but with an offset parameter of type **off_t** instead of **long**.  Setting **_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64** will make **off_t** a 64-bit type.

The same for goes for **[ftello()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/ftello.html)**.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`fsetpos(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fsetpos) and `fgetpos(3)`.  They use the `fpos_t` datatype , which I believe is guaranteed to be able to hold at least 64 bits.