# Fopen failing for binary file

Tags: c, memory-management, fopen

I have a huge binary file which is  2148181087 bytes (> 2gb)

I am trying to do `fopen (file, "r")` and it failed with

> Can not open: xyz file (Value too
>   large to be stored in data type)

I read on the man page EOVERFLOW error is received when the file size > 2gb.

The weird thing is, I use a different input file which is also "almost" as big as the first file 2142884400 bytes (also >2gb), `fopen` works fine with this.

Is there any cutoff on the file size for `fopen` or is there any alternate way to solve this?

Comment: It should be noted that for the sake of portability you should use "rb" for binary files.

Using "r" to read a binary file will fail at least on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

The cutoff is 2GB which, contrary to what you may think, is *not* 2,000,000,000 (2x1000<sup>3</sup>).

It's 2,147,483,648 (2x1024<sup>3</sup>). So your second file, which works, is actually less than 2GB in size).

2GB, in the computer world, is only 2,000,000,000 in the minds of hard drive manufacturers so they can say their disks are bigger than they really are :-) - it lets them say their disks are actually 2.1GB.

Comment: @jpinto3912: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte : "Today the usage of the unit gigabyte is still ambiguous: its value may depend on the context of usage. When referring to disk storage capacities it usually means 1000^3 bytes."

Answer (score 5):

The "alternative way to solve this" depends on which operating system/library you are using.

For the GNU C library, [you can use `fopen64`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html#index-fopen64-931) as a replacement for `fopen`; it uses 64-bit file handles (there's also a macro to have `fopen` use 64-bit file handles).

For Windows, you'll probably have to switch to the Win32 file management API, with which you can use [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I just found out from the man page about fopen64 bit system call. I am currently on the UNIX platform. I just tried this system call and it worked. 

What do you mean by 64 bit file handles? ) Is it to do something with 64 bit boundaries? 

Will it have any adverse effect while reading the binary file in the application if I use fopen64()?

Comment: The `FILE*` it returns is still the same type as returned by `fopen`, it just has the `O_LARGEFILE` flag set.  The file handle can be used like any other file handle with the typical I/O functions.

Comment: For others hitting this problem, I suggest setting -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 on your gcc command line (or equivalently in your makefile).  For some reason, using #define within your code does _not_ seem to have the same effect.  This answer provides what I consider to be the best summary for your options here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1035713/3561