# C++ 64-bit std::ostream support

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, large-files

I am about to make the transition from using standard FILE pointers from some older code to using C++ streams but I need to have LARGEFILE seeking support (the compiler flags that activate this support are: *-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64* et al) which I am able to obtain by using the *off64_t* datatype.

My [original question was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035657/seeking-and-reading-large-files-in-a-linux-c-application) regarding this subject matter and the C API, and now I am hoping to be able to transition towards using C++ streams.

Do the same flags trigger seeking ability on file streams in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I performed a quick test on a 16GB file and it seems to have worked. Here is the code that I used.

```
// compiled with : g++ -o largefile -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 largefile.cpp
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"

int
main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
        char line[4096];
        std::ifstream stream ("/home/jbellone/largefile.csv");

        // Seek forward to somewhere past 4GB
        stream.seekg (10294967296, std::ios_base::beg);

        stream.getline (line, 100);

        std::cout << stream.tellg() << " " << line << "\n";      
}
```