# How do I get the file size of a large (> 4 GB) file?

Tags: c, large-files, filesize

How can I get the file size of a file in C when the file size is greater than 4gb?

ftell returns a 4 byte signed long, limiting it to two bytes. stat has a variable of type off_t which is also 4 bytes (not sure of sign), so at most it can tell me the size of a 4gb file.

What if the file is larger than 4 gb?

Comment: On which OS?  This isn't completely standardised.

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035657/seeking-and-reading-large-files-in-a-linux-c-application

Comment: Can this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux with glibc, ftell returns an `off_t`; depending on the flags `off_t` may be 32 bit or may be 64 bit.

On Linux, you can get the appropriate flags to have a 64 bit `off_t` by doing `getconf LFS_CFLAGS` (LFS stands for large-file-support).

Comment: glibc documentation shows `ftell` returning `long int` and `ftello` returning `off_t`. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Positioning.html

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, `GetFileSize[Ex]` is what you use.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE 1
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

i think that increases the size of off_t to 64 bits on some operating systems