# Cross-platform seeking for large files

Tags: c, cross-platform, seek, fseek

Is there a cross-platform `fseek()` for large files? Seeking fails when exceeding the `2GB` limit.

```
size_t chunkSkip = 1024 * 4;
uint64_t skipped = 0;
while (skipped < args.nSkipBytes) {
    uint64_t offset;
    if (skipped + chunkSkip > args.nSkipBytes) {
        offset = args.nSkipBytes - skipped;
    }
    else {
        offset = chunkSkip;
    }
    int res = fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_CUR);
    if (res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not skip %llu bytes, file may be "
                "too small. Result: %d\n", args.nSkipBytes, res);
        charbuffer_free(printable); 
        charbuffer_free(unprintable); 
        return ECANCELED;
    }
    skipped += offset;
}
```

I've read about `_fseeki64()`, but that seems to be MSVC only? If there is not, I would be more interested in a GCC solution.

Comment: it has asnwer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035657/seeking-and-reading-large-files-in-a-linux-c-application

Comment: From the link above, this is the best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1036622/694576 I suspect you won't get around to implement two different way depending on the target OS.