# C - dynamically modifying a file - is it possible?

Tags: c, file-io

I'm writing a small program in C and I want to have the option of saving data to file and then reading it from that file. The data is BIG, so I want to somehow dynamically write to a file without having to create a new file and copy modified old file into it.

Here's exactly what I want to do:
In the first line, I want to have "description" of the data in the form "%s %s %s ... %s \n" where %s is a string and the n'th string describes data in n+1'th line. I want to read the 1'st line of the file, scan for corresponding "description" string, and if it is not present, append it to the first line, and the data corresponding to it after the last line of the file.

The question is - is it possible to "jump" into lines in the file without scanning all the previous lines, and can I somehow read the first line of the file and append something to it after reading? Or maybe it is not the way to go in this situation and C offers some kind of different solution?

Comment: Can't you just use an existing database? Maybe SQLite? If not, yes, you can jump to any position in a file and read only what it matters to you, however, you need to know the exact position beforehand, and how much data you'll read. How do you do that? Establish a fixed size for each line (or block, whatever you call it), and use a simple multiplication. However, don't expect to be able to insert a "second line" without rewriting all the next lines.

Comment: Don't use a textfile, use a binary file with fixed formatting.

Comment: Investigate [Seeking and reading large files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035657/). The answers there apply to C as well.

Comment: Unless you reserve a fixed amount of space for each record in the file, it's not going to work. Specifically, appending more information to an existing line in a file requires that you rewrite the entire file from that point forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want can be done using `stdio` and `fseek()`. As long as you know at what byte offset you want to go, you can overwrite and/or append anywhere in the file without reading the data before, or the data you're overwriting. What you can not easily do is insert data, i.e., open the file, split it in half and put data in between.

Not too sure if that is what you mean though...