# Seeking a File Position > 2^32 in C

Tags: c, file

I'm writing a program to write a lot of data to a file, but the file will eventually be large enough that I couldn't seek through it because the position would be greater than the maximum integer size on a **32-bit** computer. I would like to seek to a location at least 2^35. What is the proper way to do this?

Edit:
I am trying to make a cross-platform program, but I am currently working on a Linux 32-bit OS.

Comment: Depending on the platform you're developing for, defining `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` to `64` and using the stdlibrary functions `fseeko` and `ftello` may solve your problem.

Comment: What OS? Windows `SetFilePointer` can do 64 bit seek.

Comment: What platform?  Most 64-bit operating systems natively support files larger than 2GB.

Comment: `fseek()` is not limited to `int` size, but to `long`.  What is `LONG_MAX` on your system?

Comment: @bool3max I thought this doesn't work on a 32-bit computer. If it does work, I'm curious how considering the return value is a 4-byte long int (off_t) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You may find your answer there: [Seeking and reading large files in a Linux C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035657/seeking-and-reading-large-files-in-a-linux-c-application)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a standard linux/glibc (can't vouch for others?) environment:

- `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` -- turns `off_t` to a 64bit type
- use stdlib functions `fseeko()` and `ftello()` from *stdio.h* instead of their regular counterparts

Also see their respective manpages.